# Reduce size core dumps MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, coredump, macos-mojave

I am working on an application for MacOS. There I would like to store core dumps. But doing some tests I have seen that core files generated for MacOS are huge (more than 1 GB). Is there any way, programatically to tell OS to generate smaller core files?

I have seen the function `setrlimit`, with parameter `RLIMIT_CORE`. The documentation says it reduces the size of the core dump. But what information will be left out to make the file smaller? Can someone give some hints here?

Comment: A core dump is a dump of your processes entire memory space. It has the size of your process. Full stop. The only ways to reduce it in size are to a) compress it, or b) leave out some information (so that it will *not* actually be a full dump, but rather some reduced dump with stuff defined by you left out). Which do you want?

Comment: How could I leave out some information to reduce its size ?